# ¿como separar palabras, luego agregar una palabra (que quede tercera), despues que quede como la original con la palabra agregada?

Tags: r, condiciones, split

Quiero agregar un string (TE) o este otro (T.14) (segun si el Talle="XXXL" o Talle="14) justo después de la segunda palabra del contenido de la celda, sin ningún espacio entre la segunda palabra y el string, y que me devuelva el texto original con el string agregado.
Intenté algo así, pero no logro hacerlo bien.
Podrán ayudarme?

```
df2<-data.frame ( Descripcion = c(
          "la primer palabra la segunda la tecerda la cuarta",
          "la primer palabra la segunda la tecerda la cuarta",
          "la primer palabra la segunda la tecerda la cuarta",
          "aca puede ir otro texto",
          "aca puede ir otro texto",
          "aca puede ir otro texto",
          "aca algo distinto",
          "aca algo distinto",
          "aca algo distinto"),
          Talle=c("S","M","XXL","M","L","XXXL","10","12","14"))

df2$Descripción <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df2$Descripción), " "), function(x) {
    if (length(x) >= 2) {
        if (df2$Talle=="XXXL"|df2$Talle=="14") {
            paste(x[2],"TE")
        } else {
            df2$Descripción
        }
        else {
            df2$Descripción
        }
    }
})
```

el output esperado seria este:

```
df3<-data.frame ( Descripcion = c(
    "la primer palabra la segunda la tecerda la cuarta",
    "la primer palabra la segunda la tecerda la cuarta",
    "la primer palabra la segunda la tecerda la cuarta",
    "aca puede ir otro texto",
    "aca puede ir otro texto",
    "aca puedeTE ir otro texto",
    "aca algo distinto",
    "aca algo distinto",
    "aca algoT.14 distinto"),
    Talle=c("S","M","XXL","M","L","XXXL","10","12","14"))
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas combinando una operación por fila (lo que hace `sapply`) con un `if` que aplica a todo el `data.frame`, es decir, estás asumiendo que `df2$Talle=="XXXL"|df2$Talle=="14"` te devuelve la condición correspondiente a la fila que quieres modificar pero en realidad te retorna un vector de lógicos por todo el `data.frame`.

Yo haría lo siguiente:

```
filas_a_modificar <- df2$Talle=="XXXL"|df2$Talle=="14"
sapply(df2$Descripcion[filas_a_modificar],
       FUN=function(x) { 
                          words <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
                          if (length(words) >= 2) {
                            words[2] <- paste0(words[2], "TE")
                          }
                          paste0(words, collapse = " ")
                      }) -> df2$Descripcion[filas_a_modificar]
```

Primero obtenemos las filas a modificar y luego solo modificamos estas.

Comment: muchas gracias. funciono muy bien.
es que para simplificar puse , al final, solo modificar si Talle= XXXL, y si eso pasaba agregar TE. en el original, ademas, si Talle = 14 habia que agregar "T.14" y no "TE"